# Subset of Lebesgue measurable sets is not empty

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $l$ be the Lebesgue measure on the $\sigma$-algebra $L$ of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $A\in L$ with $l(A)>0$.
Let $U$ be an open interval such that for $0<\epsilon<1$ we have $$l(A\cap U)>\epsilon\cdot l(U).$$
Let $u\in(-1/2\cdot l(U),1/2\cdot l(U))$ and $A\cap U_{+u}=\{a+u:a\in A\cap U\}$

> How do I show that $A\cap U$ and $A\cap U_{+u}$ have non-empty intersection?

I thought that we could prove this by contradiction.
Translation doesn't change the measure, so $l(A\cap U_{+u})=l(A\cap U)$. If the intersection is empty, then 
$$l[(A\cap U)\cup(A\cap U_{+u})]=l(A\cap U)+l(A\cap U_{+u})=2l(A\cap U)>2\epsilon\cdot l(U).$$
So now I have to show that $l[(A\cap U)\cup(A\cap U_{+u})]\leq 2\epsilon\cdot l(U)$. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quantifier on your $\epsilon $ is unclear. If the only requirement is existance, then the theorem fails, since $A=(0,\frac{1}{3}) $, $U=(0,2) $, and $u=\frac{1}{2} $ demonstrates.

Assuming that it is for all epsilon, take $\epsilon=\frac{3}{4} $. Assuming without loss of generality that $u\geq 0$, it then follows that $[A\cap U]\cup [A\cap U_{+u}]\subseteq U\cup (U+u) $. Thus for $U=(a,b) $, $[A\cap U]\cup [A\cap U_{+u}]\subseteq (a,b+u) $. Hence $l ([A\cap U]\cup [A\cap U_{+u}])\leq l ((a,b+u))=u+(b-a)\leq \frac {1}{2}l (U)+l (U)$, giving the desired contradiction.

Comment: You were right, it is for all $\epsilon$.

Comment: Why can we take $U=(a,b)$? I thought it was just an open interval

Comment: @AlexPapadimitriou what's your definition of an open interval?

Comment: I thought it could also be infinite

Comment: @AlexPapadimitriou then the strict inequality in the statement of the problem doesn't make sense.

Comment: I see. Another question (if that's okay), why is $l((a,b+u))=u+(b-a)\leq \frac{1}{2}l(U)+l(U)$?

Comment: Could you please take a look at my question above?

Comment: @AlexPapadimitriou I didn't see the question before now. Go through the definitions. What is $u$? What about $a $ and $b $?

Comment: Well $U=(a,b)$ and $u\in(-\frac{1}{2}l(U),\frac{1}{2}l(U))$, but I don't see why that gives it. I think I'm not familiar enough with the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$